Product of quotients of gamma functions: bounding $\frac{\Gamma(y + |k - x|)\ \Gamma(1 + |k|)}{\Gamma(1 + |k-x|)\ \Gamma(y + |k|)}$
I'm trying to prove an identity regarding gamma functions. Assuming $0 < y < 1$ and $x > 0$:
$$
\max_k
\frac{\Gamma(y + |k - x|)\ \Gamma(1 + |k|)}{\Gamma(1 + |k-x|)\ \Gamma(y + |k|)}
= \frac{\Gamma(y)\ \Gamma(1 + x)}{\Gamma(y + x)}
$$
i.e. this is maximized when $k = x$.
Numerically this appears to be the case, but basic gamma identities aren't getting me anywhere.
It seems true that $\max_k \frac{\Gamma(y + |k - x|)}{\Gamma(1 + |k - x|)} = \Gamma(y)$ which might help, but I'm not even 100% sure how to prove that.
Even with that result in hand, the other term $\frac{\Gamma(1 + |k|)}{\Gamma(y + |k|)}$ is definitely not maximized at $k = x$ so we can't just
go term by term.
There are some identities I saw which operate on quotients of gamma functions (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautschi%27s_inequality),
but none seem to match the setting completely (i.e. in the language of that wiki page we have $Γ(x + s)$ and $Γ(x + 1)$ where $x = 0$ but the identities require $x > 0$).

I think I can solve the simpler problem assuming $k$ and $x$ are integers.
There are three cases:

$k = x$. In this case the quantity is $A = \frac{\Gamma(y)\Gamma(1+x)}{\Gamma(y + x)}$.
$k = 0$. In this case the quantity is $B = \frac{\Gamma(y + x)}{\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(y)}$
$k \notin \{x, 0\}$.

$A \ge B$ because $\Gamma(y) \ge 1$ and $\Gamma(1 + x) \ge \Gamma(y + x)$ for $x \ge 1$.
For the third case, consider the quantity $\Delta = |k| - |k-x|$ which we know is an integer. We'll use the identity $(z)_n = \frac{\Gamma(z + n)}{\Gamma(z)} = z(z+1)...(z + n - 1)$ for an integer $n \ge 0$.
$$
\begin{align*}
C &=\frac{\Gamma(y + |k - x|)}{y + |x|}\frac{\Gamma(1 + |k|)}{\Gamma(1 + |k-x|)}\\
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{(1 + |k-x|)_\delta}{(y + |k-x|)_\delta} & \text{ if $\delta \ge 0$ }\\
\frac{(y + |k|)_\delta}{(1 + |k|)_\delta} & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
The $\delta \ge 0$ term dominates. So it suffices to show:
$$
\begin{align*}
A = \frac{\Gamma(y)\Gamma(1+x)}{\Gamma(y + x)} &= \Gamma(y) \frac{1(2)...(x-1)...x}{y (y + 1) ... (y + x - 1)\Gamma(y)}\\
&= \frac{(1)_\delta}{(y)_\delta}\\
&\ge \frac{(1 + |k-x|)_\delta}{(y + |k-x|)_\delta}
\end{align*}
$$
The last inequality follows from the fact that adding a constant term to the numerator and denominator of a fraction that is less than one only decreases it, i.e. $\frac{a+|n|}{b + |n|} \le \frac{a}{b}$ if $a\ge b$. This follows from the mediant inequality.
